# How to use an OR statement in a Post-Build event?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

I am trying to use a conditional with an OR in a Post-Build event, but so far, I have had not luck.  The following does not work:

`if not "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug" or not "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" (`

but this works:

`if not "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug" (`

With the first one, I get an exist code 4.

Answer (score 12):

It seems like there is no provision for OR/AND in conditionals in Pre-Post Build events, at least according to its lack of documentation over here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx

You would have to re-write your IF statement to do what you would want to do.

```
if not "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug" (
   rem do something
) else if not "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" (
   rem do the same thing as above
)
```

Hope that helps, though your conditions don't make sense to me. :-)

Comment: I think he he created a custom configuration (or perhaps more than one) and he wants to target those instead of Debug/Release.

Comment: Anyway, I tried this solution to a similar problem. It worked for me but I had to remove the double quotes as in if not $(ConfigurationName) == Debug  . Maybe both works

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute some logic in a Post-Build event where the ConfigurationName is not "Debug" or "Release", try the following:

`if not "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug" (if not "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" (***ADD LOGIC HERE - ConfigurationName is not "Debug" or "Release"***))`